# Mouse orientation changes and it doesn't fold/unfold a block of code or text

Tags: mouse, windows-11

When I click on minus/plus sign, It doesn't fold/unfold a block of text/code. I've tried Notepad++ and VS and in both, it doesn't work. I tried another mouse and it didn't work either. From a remote desktop session,ho9wever, it works!

I don't know why this has happened!

Any suggestions?

EDIT 1: I noticed when the mouse is close to the vertical line, the mouse cursor orientation changes to right orientation. I Edited to title to reflect this.

[image]

Comment: @jsotola, Thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: maybe your mouse does not register clicks... does it work for everything else?

Comment: @jsotola Yes it works fine. BTW, I found that mouse orientation has changed in this area. It becomes right orientation.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall Notepad++?